# Trying to get string if there are authors, title, publisher, etc

Tags: java, android, json

In my book listing app, I'm parsing the JSON to extract the information I need, such as author, publisher, title, etc.  For this, I'm using an if statement to get the string if the desired string exists.  Below is the method where I'm doing this.

```
private static List<Books> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJSON) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJSON)) {return null;}

        List<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
            JSONArray booksArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < booksArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentBook = booksArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                JSONArray authorsArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                String title, publisher, publishedDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating, authors = "";

                if(volumeInfo.has("title")){
                    language = volumeInfo.getString("language");
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < authorsArray.length(); j++) {
                    if (volumeInfo.has("authors")){
                        authors = authorsArray.getString(j);
                    }
                }

                if(volumeInfo.has("publisher")){
                    publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                }


                if(volumeInfo.has("publishedDate")){
                    publishedDate = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");
                }

                if(volumeInfo.has("language")){
                    language = volumeInfo.getString("language");
                }

                if(volumeInfo.has("pageCount")){
                    pageCount = volumeInfo.getString("pageCount");
                }

                if(volumeInfo.has("printType")){
                    printType = volumeInfo.getString("printType");
                }

                if(volumeInfo.has("maturityRating")){
                    maturityRating = volumeInfo.getString("maturityRating");
                }

                Books book = new Books(title, authors, publisher, publishedDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating);
                books.add(book);
            }


        }
```

However, the parameters in

```
Books book = new Books(title, authors, publisher, publishedDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating);
                books.add(book);
```

show an error that says variable 'x' might not have been initialized.  Anyway I can come across this?  I appreciate all help.

This is the JSON Google API: `"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?maxResults=40&q="`

And here is the error log:

```
Error:(145, 40) error: variable title might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 56) error: variable publisher might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 67) error: variable publishedDate might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 82) error: variable language might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 92) error: variable pageCount might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 103) error: variable printType might not have been initialized
Error:(145, 114) error: variable maturityRating might not have been initialized
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Share your json response.

Comment: Need more information. Can you share the Json String, And Error Log

Comment: Yep.  Its up there now.

Comment: The first conditional statement setting `language` depending on `title` looks off.

Comment: You use these variables to construct a `Books` (please rethink that class name: one book or multiple books?), whether they have been set or not. (And do everyone (foremost yourself) a favour and comment your code properly.)

Comment: You could have tried to provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare some strings in your code.

`String title, publisher, publishedDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating, authors = "";`

But as the error message tells you only the last one is initialized.
You have to initialize all variables. Like so:

`String title = "", publisher = "", publishedDate = "", language = "", pageCount = "", printType = "", maturityRating = "", authors = "";`

Comment: Actually, sorry.  It didn't because now all my authors are invisible.